# Active record query on will_paginate

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

I want to use this query on `will_paginate`:

```
@courses = Course.where("id not in (?)", current_user.courses).paginate :page => params[:page], :order => 'code asc'
```

It doesn't get me the results I want, unfortunately.

Comment: What's wrong with the results you get? Are they ordered incorrectly, is the where clause not working or are the pages wrong?

Comment: the pagination dissapears. thats what I use in my controller:     `  if current_user.courses.empty?
    @courses = Course.paginate :page => params[:page], :order => 'code asc'
    else
    @courses = Course.where("id not in (?)", current_user.courses).paginate :page => params[:page], :order => 'code asc'
    end`

Comment: Can you post the SQL that is generated?  I'm guessing that current_user.courses is returning an array of course objects.  You probably want an array of course id for the in clause...

Comment: Is the problem that the pagination links disappear?  If so, it's because you may have less than the 30 records that will_paginate defaults to.  Try adding a `:per_page => 2` to your query.

Comment: Hey it worked. I added the `:per_page`. Thanks very much Brian :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the `:per_page` parameter. Courtesy brian.